# Writing in csv file from a list

Tags: python, csv, class, oop

I am writing a class that should write a csv file with a delimiter `','`

```
class DelFile(WriteFile):
    def __init__(self, TextFile):
        self.TextFile = TextFile

    def write(self, Mssg, Delimiter):
        with open(self.TextFile, "w+") as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
            for item in Mssg:
                writer.writerow(item)
```

I am calling it here:

```
c = DelFile('text3.csv')
c.write(['a','b','c'], ',')
```

As a result, I get this:

[image]

I would like to write the content **as rows and not as columns** `a, b, c.` Also, I did not understand why the result is jumping lines. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: change `for item in Mssg:
                writer.writerow(item)` to `writer.writerow(Mssg)`

Comment: the other is a classic dupe: `with open(self.TextFile, "w+") as csv_file:
` => `with open(self.TextFile, "w",newline="") as csv_file:` in python 3 or you get extra carriage return

Comment: Are you on Windows? The writer will jump lines on Windows unless you specify `newline` like `with open(self.TextFile, "w+", newline='') as csv_file:` in Python 3, or  with `"wb"` in Python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, in Python 3.x when working with `csv.writer()` objects, files should be opened with the `newline=''` argument. Secondly, you are passing a whole row to your `write()` function, and `writerow()` takes a whole row, there is no need to split it into individual values with a for loop. As you have seen, this the results in each value be written as a separate row. Instead simply write the whole row as follows:

```
import csv

class DelFile():
    def __init__(self, TextFile):
        self.TextFile = TextFile

    def write(self, row, delimiter):
        with open(self.TextFile, 'w+', newline='') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=delimiter)
            writer.writerow(row)

c = DelFile('text3.csv')
c.write(['a','b','c'], ',')
```

This would give you `text3.csv` containing:

```
a,b,c
```

Note: This approach is very inefficient, as you are effectively opening and appending a file for every row. This might be ok if you only write a few rows, but perhaps a better approach would be to keep the file open until the class is deleted.